# Is scrypt a hashing function, encryption, or PBKDF?

Tags: pbkdf-2, scrypt

I have installed a python implementation of scrypt and noticed it has several functions, both an encrypt and hash function. Yet Wikipedia lists it as being used for PBKDF instead of PBKDF2. Is scrypt a hashing function for PBKDF2 or is it on its own an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scrypt is most certainly a password-based-key-derivation-function.  So is PBKDF2, although it can be confusing since PBKDF2 is an [eponym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym).  To add to the confusion, Scrypt uses PBKDF2 internally (which may be the hashing function you refer to), as well as the Salsa20/8 Core function (which may be the encryption function you refer to).  Further reading [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8634/how-does-scrypt-use-salsa).

Answer (score 2):

PBKDF2 and scrypt are both password based key derivation functions (PBKDF's). scrypt is different in the fact that it has a large internal state. This means that it is hard to create a hardware accelerator for it. This means that an attacker cannot use a hardware implementation to gain advantage over the legitimate user.

For more information, please see the rather extensive [Wikipedia page about scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt).